# Поиск слов в различных формах в тексте из формы на сайте

Tags: javascript

Существует ли библиотека или что-то подобное, что позволяет находить слова (из массива, например) в различных формах (падеж, лицо и т.д.) в тексте, введённом в форму html. Т.е. скрипт анализирует введённый текст и всегда найдёт, например, слово "Чёрт", "Черти" и т.д.

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос, так-то и средства обычного js могут искать в строке (чем является значение из поля ввода) конкретную подстроку (слово из словаря), может вам нужен всего-то [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Библиотеки существуют, flexsearch например (первое что в гугле выпало).

Answer (score 0):

Называется это "поиск с учетом морфологии".

Вообще, одними библиотеками тут не обойдешься. Нужен еще какой-то морфологический анализ. Например, "Попугай" - это и сущ. и.п. ед.ч., и глаг. пов.накл. от "Попугать" == преф. "по-" + "Пугать".

Морф. словари тоже есть, но в разборе словосочетания "...иди, попугай" не сильно они помогут. Нужен контекст и не оч. простая программная логика...